# Wpf Binding Dicionaly with key and list on objects to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a question.

As one of my View model properties I have a dictionary like:

```
    private Dictionary<int, List<RackPresentation>> racksPresentation;
    public Dictionary<int, List<RackPresentation>> RacksPresentation
    {
        get => racksPresentation;
        set
        {
            racksPresentation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Well simple property using notification. Now I am trying to bind it to ListView, bit It seems I am stuck because value of a dictionary is a list of models object and i cant get to their properties, my xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RacksPresentation}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
           <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}" />
           <!-- some grid or data grad to present values properties from dictionary value -->
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

Is there a simple solution to this problem?